# Nested IF statement to check between values

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-docs

I'm struggling with an IF statement in Google Docs.

I'm using it financially to find out interest accrued on a value.

Interest is either 1%, 2% or 3% depending on the amount.

If the amount is between £0 and £1999 then 1% is given
If it is between £2000 and £2999 then 2% is given
And anything over £3000 comes to 3%

Here is my attempt:

```
=IF(M8>=3000,(M8/100)*3,IF(M8<2999),(M8/100)*2,IF(M8<1999),(M8/100)*1)
```

My thought process here was that it would first check for the `>=3000` and work out 3%. If that statement wasn't true it would continue on to the 2% calc and so on.

But this doesn't work. I get `"wrong number of arguments for IF"` error

Comment: You are  missing parentheses: `=IF(M8>=3000,(M8/100)*3,IF((M8<2999),(M8/100)*2,IF((M8<1999),(M8/100)*1)))` but also your logic is not correct. If M8=1000 it will calculate the 2% rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not closing the IF statements properly and you only need two.

The logic should be: if number is more than or equal to 3000, multiply by 3, if number is less than 3000, but more than 1999(more than or equal to 2000) multiply by 2, in any other case (when number is less than or equal to 1999) multiply by 1.

Here is a working function

```
=IF(M8>=3000,(M8/100)*3,IF(AND(M8>1999,M8<3000),(M8/100)*2,(M8/100)*1))
```